# How to apply 3D effect to HR tag

Tags: html, css

I am Trying  to add 3D style for "hr" tag but I am not satisfied with my CSS. Please give me an idea about it sorry for my bad English.

```css
hr{
  color:red;
  box-shadow:3px 3px 3px red;
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Style</h1>
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created this one

```css
hr {
  margin-top:50px  
}

hr.one {
  border-color:red;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 0px pink;
}

hr.two {
  border:4px solid red;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 0px pink;
}

hr.three {
  border:4px solid red;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 4px pink;
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Style</h1>

<hr class="one"/>
<hr class="two"/>
<hr class="three"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be classic 3D HR (you can tweak it to suit your needs):

```css
hr{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #DFDFDF;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```